# How to get data from two table that using same primary key

Tags: sql, database

I have four tables: `Books`, `Magazine`, `Member` and `Transaction` and each has a column `Title`.

**Books** table

```
BookId,   Title,           author,        edition,    no_of_books
1,        Harry Potter,    Jk rowling,    5,          11
```

**Magazine** table:

```
MagazineId,    Title,      Publisher,    edition,   no_of_magazine
1,             filmfare,   bollywood,    5,         8
```

**Member** table:

```
MemberId,    name,    address,              contact,    email
4,           Arjun,   NO 56 park street,    071487845,  arjun56@gmail.com
8,           khan,    no 21 new lane pune,  07487547,   khan@gmail.com
```

When members borrow a `Book` or a `Magazine`, the `Transaction` table keeps records (`Trans_item_id` is `BookId` or `MagazineId`)

For example:

**Transaction** table:

```
Trans_Id, Trans_Mem_Id, Trans_item_Id, Issue_date, Receive_date,Category
1, 4, 1,06-04-2016, 10-04-2016,book
2, 8, 1,08-04-2016, 11-04-2016,magazine
```

So how can select data from database using SQL and display order to this

ex:

```
Tran_id, Title, member name, issue date, receive date
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your problem here is your design. You should not have separate table for books and magazines. You should have a single table of Items and a column for type.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.tran_id,
  case when t.category = 'books' then b.title else t.title end AS title,
  u.name,
  t.issue_date,
  t.receive_date
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN member u
ON t.trans_mem_id = u.memberid
LEFT JOIN books b
ON t.trans_item_id = b.bookid
AND t.category     = 'books'
LEFT JOIN magazines m
ON t.trans_item_id = m.magazineid
AND t.category     = 'magazines'
```

Comment: You need to change the joins to OUTER.

Comment: What is that DECODE function? That is not something I have seen before.

Comment: Decode is an Oracle function that work as a CASE WHEN. I'll change that on my answer as the database is not specified.

Comment: No need to change your answer I am just not familiar with it. I am a sql server guy and can't even spell Oracle correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

select 
        t.trans_item_id as tran_id, 
        coalesce(b.title, ma.title), 
        m.name, t.issue_date, t.receive_date 
    from 
        transaction t 
    inner join 
        member m on m.memberid = t.trans_mem_id 
    left join 
        books b  on t.trans_item_id = b.bookid
left join 
    magazine ma on t.trans_item_id = ma.Magazineid

Comment: You're using the `m` alias twice - not clear which table with an `m` alias you're referring to in your column list....

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the one more column for type whether borrowed item is book/magazine...

```
Select 
    t.Tran_ID,
    case 
       when t.type = 'book' 
         then 
            (select title from book where book.I'd = t.transitemid) 
         else 
            (select title from magazine where magazineid = t.tranitemid) 'title',
    m.member name, t.receivedate 
from 
    transaction t, membertable m 
where 
    t.Tranmemberid = m.memberid
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The category field is used for that, I believe.

Comment: @marc_s, unrelated, but I was wondering about that when I started learning more about SQL. That's how I was taught in my database class... That I took in 2015 at an accredited university. O.o Thanks for unknowingly clearing up my curiosity!